# Add 'active' class to navigation links de

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add an `active` class to the navigation link depending on which page im on.

Here is my navigation bar code.

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using any framework? What server side language are you using? if any? You can achieve this with server side language (e.g. PHP), or with javascript. If you are not using either one, and the menu is copied over and over on every page then you can just add it manually.

Comment: What code languages are you willing to use for it? With html it won't be possible, I think so. Please specify your content or tags to this.

Comment: @gdaniel he added the dynamic tag so he probably won't do it manually. Also he added the addclass tag which could refer to the jquery function `addClass` so he might be using a jquery library

Comment: @gdaniel im using php.

Comment: @Fleuv all valid points. I forgot to check the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it's done in PHP.

```
<?php
    $menu = array(
        array(
            'href' => 'index.php',
            'text' => 'Index',
        ),
        array(
            'href' => 'test.php',
            'text' => 'Test',
        ),
    );
?>
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <?php
            foreach ($menu as $link) {
                $item='<li>';
                if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1) == $link['href']) {
                    $item.='<a href="'.$link['href'].'" class="active">'.$link['text'].'</a>';
                } else {
                    $item.='<a href="'.$link['href'].'">'.$link['text'].'</a>';
                }
                $item.='</li>';
                print $item;
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Like you can see I've used an array instead of some plain HTML, I suggest you to do the same for as many things as possible. This makes your code more "dynamic" and has many benefits.

---

Here is how it's done in JavaScript

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.php">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var menu = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li a');
    for (var i = menu.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (menu[i].href==document.URL) {
            menu[i].setAttribute("class", "active");
        }
    };
</script>
```

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fleuv/t6tpawc2/)

---

And not to forget, the jQuery of doing it..

```
<nav>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">Index</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.php">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.menu li a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('href')==location.pathname.substr(1)){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fleuv/gszs7a3q/)

Comment: @DarkKing Sure there is, hold on I'll edit my answer within an half hour. Going to eat now :D

Comment: Okay. I will be waiting.

Comment: @DarkKing check it out, added the javascript and jQuery version of it!

Comment: @HassanZia as long as you're able to read the URL where the button is linking to. Than just read that and compare it with the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css styling to do this.

css file

```
#navigation li a.current{
   color: #ffffff;
   background:#000000;
}
```

html file

```
<div id="navigation">
            <ul class="nav">

                <li><a class="current" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to add it to be added dynamically. Like it detects which page im on. And add a class of 'active' to that page's navigation link.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery solve this issue

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.nav li a').on('click', function(event) {
                $('.nav li a').removeClass('active').removeAttr('class');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by jQuery, you can do that too. Here's how.

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    // Get the last item in the path (e.g. index.php)
    let url = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();

    // Add active nav class based on url
    $("#navigation ul li a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("href") == url || $(this).attr("href") == '') {
            $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
        }
    })

    // Add the active class into Home if user omit index.php from url
    if (url == '') {
        $("#navigation ul li").eq(0).addClass("active");
    }
});
```